# Auto scroll image taller than container on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want a script/css such that on hovering a image which is taller than the container it is in will auto scroll inside the container and will come back to its original position on hover out.
I am really bad at javascript still I have found a code for this but it does not seem to work.

The HTML

```
<span class="keymel dhiraj">
<img width="300px" height="auto" src="http://dribbble.s3.amazonaws.com/users/197532/screenshots/1145931/freebie-1.png" style="top: 0px" /></span>
```

The CSS

```
.keymel {
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
float: left;
height: 80px;
margin-left: 3px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
width: 300px;
border:5px solid #DDD;}
img {
position: absolute;
transition: top 1s ease-out 0s;}
```

The JS

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var xH
$('.dhiraj').hover(
function() {
xH = $(this).children("img").css("height");
xH = parseInt(xH);
xH = xH - 150;
xH = "-" + xH + "px";
$(this).children( "img" ).css("top",xH);
}, function() {
$(this).children( "img" ).css("top","0px");
}
);
});
```

I have created a small example in Jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/VuTYx/1/

Please help me out.

Comment: is this what you wanted? http://jsfiddle.net/VuTYx/3/ you seem to miss jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JS appears to have been working, but the code included jQuery while the Fiddle didn't have jQuery enabled. I enabled jQuery and it seems to work as you described: http://jsfiddle.net/VuTYx/2/

Make sure that jQuery is correctly included in your project by adding something like:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: My fault. There was something wrong with one of the css styles. Thanks for helping by the way.

Comment: Glad you found the culprit. Best of luck.

Comment: CSS3 is one solution, but keep in mind that a different approach is required for each browser. For example, your solution doesn't work for me because I'm not browsing in FireFox. This approach will also not work on older versions of IE.

Answer (score 2):

Not Need Jquery Only By Css

see this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/modaloda/Pb3np/3/)

Css only :

```
.komal {
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
float: left;
height: 80px;
margin-left: 3px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
width: 300px;
border:5px solid #DDD;
}
img {
position: absolute;
transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}

 .komal:hover >img
 {  
 -moz-animation: border-bounce 3000ms linear;
 -webkit-animation: border-bounce 3000ms linear;
 }
 @-moz-keyframes border-bounce {
 0%   { margin-top: -10px;  }
 25%  { margin-top: -50px; }
 50%  { margin-top: -100px;  }
 75%  { margin-top: -50px;  }
 100% { margin-top: -0px;  }
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes border-bounce {
 0%   { margin-top: -10px;  }
 25%  { margin-top: -50px; }
 50%  { margin-top: -100px;  }
 75%  { margin-top: -50px;  }
 100% { margin-top: -0px;  }
 }
```

Comment: CSS3 is one solution, but keep in mind that a different approach is required for each browser. For example, your solution doesn't work for me because I'm not browsing in FireFox. This approach will also not work on older versions of IE.